# LiveData Obserever catch only first value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I get list of issues from Firebase Database and return `LiveData`.

```
fun getAllIssues(): MutableLiveData<IssueEntity> {
    val issues: MutableLiveData<IssueEntity> = MutableLiveData()
    val issuesReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("issues")
    issuesReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            if (snapshot == null) {
                return
            }
            snapshot.children.forEach({
                val issueMessage = it.child("message").value.toString()
                val issueTitle = it.child("title").value.toString()
                val issueOwner = it.child("owner").value.toString()

                issues.postValue(IssueEntity(issueTitle, issueMessage, issueOwner))
            })
        }
    })
    return issues
}
```

Code of my Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_issues)
    val issues: MutableList<IssueEntity> = mutableListOf()
    issuesList.adapter = IssuesAdapter(issues)
    IssueRepository().getAllIssues().observe(this, Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            issues.add(it)
            val issuesAdapter = issuesList.adapter as IssuesAdapter
            issuesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
}
```

But Observer gets only first value. Could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. I just need to return not just MutableLiveData and MutableLiveData>